# error : "Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal" await web3.Eth.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(transactionInput); In c#

Tags: sendtransaction

Every thing is working fine till I execute

```
var transactionHash = await web3.Eth.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(transactionInput)
await web3.Eth.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAsync(transactionInput);
```

> error : Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal"

Neither I am passing decimal nor I am expecting decimal